# DataMapper Pattern with m:n relation (Domain Driven Design)

Tags: php, service, domain-driven-design, relationship, datamapper

I am currently refactoring my software according to the Domain Driven Design. The problem is my understanding in the DataMapper part, specifically if some data have `m:n` relationship via a connection table (in case of SQL).

In this case I have a Domain Object:

```
class UserGroup extends DomainObject {
    public $title;
    public $description;    
}
```

Now in my understanding, I would get an Object this way:

```
$userGroup = UserGroupMapper::instance()->findById(42);
$userGroup->title = 'Foo';
$userGroup->description = 'Bar';
UserGroupMapper::instance()->save($userGroup);
```

Am I on the right way, right now?

So here comes the problem:

I have 3 Tables:

*core_users*

```
id | etc
```

*core_usergroups*

```
id | title | description
```

*core_usergroups_dependencys*

```
usergroup_id | user_id
```

Basicly, the goal is, to find all Users which are in a specific group (or the inverted way)

The first thing, which comes to my mind:

```
$userGroup = UserGroupMapper::instance()->findById(42);
$userCollection = UserGroupMapper::instance()->findUsersByGroup($userGroup);
```

The DataMapper knows 2 tables and 2 Domain Objects, but this doesn't feel right, does it?

I don't understand the Service Part of DDD. According to it (in my understanding) I would write

```
UserGroupService::instance()->findUsers($userGroup);
```

But in this case the service need an own Data Mapper. Why shouldn't I call

```
UserGroupDependencyMapper::instance()->findUsersByGroup($userGroup);
UserGroupDependencyMapper::instance()->findGroupsByUser($user);
```

I generaly dont understand the mapping for dependency. A DataMapper should everytime return an object instance or a collection of object instances of the same type. But here, the mapper could return either a user or a group.

So, what is the way I should go for such a common problem? Bonus: What should my service do in this Example?

**Update to Clarify**

My question is not about working with the data in Domain Driven Design. It is about how can i fetch a list of data in m:n relation without fetching all. How should the Interface look like?

Basicly i need this according to the DataMapper pattern:

```
select * from core_users
join core_usergroups_dependency on core_users.id = core_usergroups_dependency.user_id
where core_usergroups_dependency.usergruop_id = 42
```

But where would the Call `findUsersByUserGroup($myGroup)` Call be located? UserMapper?

If i have that Mapper or how ever we will call this, which part knows about it? The Domain Repository?

Comment: Your main problem is that you're saying you want to use DDD but you're talking about tables, persistence details. DDD ignores the db, you only have the repository interface

Comment: Sure. But my Problem ist not the DDD. The problem is the implementation of the persistence layer which is part of DDD.

Comment: @MikeSW I mean, my Question is about the repository interface  respectively the implemenation of it.

Comment: DDD doesn't care about persistence, it's about modelling the business logic according to the domain. How you implement the persistence is your business, DDD is unrelated to it. The only thing connected to persistence is the repository interface which in DDD always works with aggregate roots. When dealing with persistence, once the repository interface is defined DDD ends. So you can go wild with the implementation and you never change the interface to accommodate the implementation.

Comment: @MikeSW okay, but if it would be my buisness logic, you are requesting me, to findAll 42.000.000 users and 42.000 user groups to checking in the buisness logic the relation for each other? Or did I understand something wrong? In theroy with 100 records ok, but in the real world with billions of records a big performance break.

Comment: I doubt that your domain needs to work with 42 mil users at once. The domain repos care _only_ for Domain's needs, we leave UI and reporting queries outside. The proper modelling matters a lot here, an aggregate root is NOT a container of entities, it's a concept.  There's only one use case executing and usually it involves just a couple of entities. Now, there are cases where you need to update bulk so first [read this](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2013/12/16/Bulk-Actions-With-DDD-And-CQRS.aspx) to see if it applies to you. But if you really have to update 10k users because they ...

Comment: all changed their names at once, then you have an exceptional case and we come up with a specific solution just for that case. But that should happen VERY rarely.

Comment: @MikeSW thanks for the link and starting point to google about it. I will take a look into this tomorow, it has 34 degrees here ;) And it is 22 o'clock in germany :/

Comment: Have you considered using an existing ORM? I suggest you take a look at the [Doctrine 2 ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/), as it's build around the Data Mapper Pattern.

Comment: @JasperN.Brouwer Sure i have taken a look in it. But how would i solve my Problem with Doctrine? Maybe i should clarify: It is not about how to work with data. My Question is about how to read the data by condition of a m:n relation (Without loading all and then check for the condition).

Comment: @MikeSW i have updated my question with a little bit more specific details. My Problem is general in getting the data, not in working with it or providing buisnees/value objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is part of the repository interface definition (defined in the Domain). The **implementation** is part of the persistence and does the actual query. The Domain services will know only about the abstraction.

```
// in the Domain

interface IUsersRepository  // I think we need a better name
{
    public function getUsersByGroup($myGroup);
}

class MyDomainService
{
    private $repo; 

    public function __construct(IUsersRepository $repo)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }

    public function doSomething($group)
    {
        $groups = $this->repo->getUsersByGroup($group);
        // process $groups
    }
}

// in DAL

class MyRepo implements IUsersRepository
{
    // implementation
}
```

What matters here is that the Domain doesn't know about *how* you get those groups. Only the implementation knows that, so you can do whatever query you want there. The Domain is decoupled from  the query itself.

Comment: Thank you so much :) One last Question. Is my Assumption right, that `MyDomainService` have 2 Methods `getUserGroupById($id)` and `getUserGroupRootAggregate($userGroup)` or how would my Presentation Layer tell, i want group with id 42?

Comment: The presentation will use a different interface and probably a different implementation which will return just the data the UI needs i.e use CQRS (have one domain model with business rules and another simple one for queries) . For some parts of the app, the model will be simple enough to be used for both purposes. But you need to remember that Domain cares only for Domain needs, never for UI or others. Other layers get their own interfaces and maybe implementations